# Three vertically stacked DIVs with scrolling middle

Tags: css, html, scroll

Is it possible to stack three DIVs vertically and have just the middle div scroll vertically?  I don't want to use pixel heights, though, because the DIVs are inside of a dialog box that is resizeable.  Something like this (pardon my lousy ASCII art):

```
+-----------+
|  Header   |
+-----------+
|          ^|
|          ||
|  Scroll  ||
|          ||
|          v|
+-----------+
|  Footer   |
+-----------+
```

The goal is to have the header and and footer fixed and, as the dialog grows, the middle div would grow vertically.  Maybe I'm just being stupid, but I've been fighting this for the last few hours and can't seem to get it right.  The three DIVs probably need to be inside "another" DIV but when I do that, and set the height to 100%, it grows as the middle DIV grows.  Again, it's probably something silly I'm not accounting for.  I've also tried using a TABLE to no avail.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is [this](http://limpid.nl/lab/css/fixed/header-and-footer) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work

```
<div id="header" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; height:50px;overflow:hidden;">
</div>
<div id="content" style="position:absolute; top:50px; bottom:50px; left:0px; overflow:auto;">
</div>
<div id="footer" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; height:50px; left:0px; overflow:hidden;">
</div>
```

---

**Edited - For fixed position header and footer in modal dialog**

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:100%; width:100%;">
    <div id="header" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; height:50px;overflow:hidden;">
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="position:absolute; top:50px; bottom:50px; left:0px; overflow:auto;">
    </div>
    <div id="footer" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; height:50px; left:0px; overflow:hidden;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Close, except that (as in the other answer) the divs are absolutely positioned.  Is there a way using "relative" positioning to the parent element?  I suppose I could start making "all" of the DIVs absolute positioning.

Comment: ok so you have these in a modal dialog and that is your problem? correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm fiddling with what you posted now.  Will try the edited version.

Comment: Excellent, thanks to both of you.  I went with the 2nd answer (edited).  I think the main source of my problem came in not understanding that absolute positioning was based on the first parent that had a position (i.e. in this case, the relative one).  Once I saw how you did it, it made complete sense to me.  Thanks for the help, both of you!

Comment: Can this be done (in the modal popup case) without a fixed height for the header, e.g., if the height of the header is going to change depending on its contents? The header should be just tall enough to contain its children, whatever they may be, the footer will have a fixed height, and the content in the center div should take up the rest, scrolling to show overflow.

Comment: @nekno yes this can be done in a modal you just have to make sure you have a relative wrapper inside the modal.

Answer (score 18):

Revisiting this for 2017. With flexbox, this can now be done without having to explicitly define the height of the header and footer. This works, at least prefixed, in all browsers that currently have any significant market share except IE <=10, which still has 1-5% share depending who you ask. Because this is generally a visual/usability mechanism and does not block functionality, using flexbox for this case should at least leave your page usable for users of unsupported browsers.

All you need to do is wrap your header, content and footer in a div that has limited height (for example, by setting the `height` or `max-height` properties as long as they are not relative to a container that will grow with content). One way is for `<html>` and `<body>` to have 100% height and for the container be a direct child of body, but there are other ways. Container should have styles:

```
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
```

And apply the style to the scrollable pane:

```
  overflow-y: auto;
```

If you want the scrollable pane to grow so all vertical space is used:

```
  flex-grow: 1;
```

and on the header and footer (necessary for Safari and IE 10):

```
  flex-grow: 0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ornsk10a/

Comment: what if the parent div doesn't have explicit height?

Comment: @Arch1tect this will work as long as there is some CSS applied that will limit the height of the containing element. I am revising my answer.

Comment: yep, the container must have explicit height defined, agree.

Comment: @AdamLeggett This is really helpfull! I was struggling to hide scrollbars within my PWA on safari to give my PWA a more native feel. I gave up. Then I came across this post. Now my scrollbar isn't overlapping my header and footer which gives my PWA a great native feel boost. Many thanks!

Comment: @dexter you're welcome. Flexbox is there to help you lay out apps - some people prefer to default to it for everything other than articles/actual text content.